# connecting grunt-contrib-sass to yeoman and grunt-contrib-watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-watch

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881958/configure-grunt-contrib-sass-in-yeoman).

I've installed the node lib and have it in my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.6.0"
}
```

and have a block in my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ...
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/scss',
        src: ['scss/{,*/}*.scss'],
        dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/css',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  }
```

My file structure looks like so:

```
app
  styles
    css
    scss
```

And I have the sass gem installed.

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here that needs to be included. My `yo serve` doesn't seem to be putting the files in the right place to be caught up and used.

I imagine theres something I'm missing in the `watch` block, but I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 0):

so my `Gruntfile.js` needed to look like this:

```
    sass: {
      dist: {
       files: [{
         expand: true,
         cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/scss',
         src: ['*.scss'],
         dest: '.tmp/styles/',
         ext: '.css'
       }]
     }
   }
```

and I needed to add `sass` to the styles task in the `watch` block.